# Is there any solution of "JavaScript heap out of memory" & "Array buffer failed"?

Tags: javascript, webpack, out-of-memory, arraybuffer

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvVHl.jpg)

I'm building a website with react. But suddenly when I entered npm run start after some time it gave me errors

1. Fatal error: NewSpace:: Rebalance Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2. Array buffer allocation failed

Comment: you probably have a memory leak in some bad code

Comment: Did you increase the heap space?

Comment: `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096`

Comment: Use a different build tool, one that is not as demanding on memory as webpack. Or just restart it every now and then. This problem will not affect the actual website that you're building.

Answer (score 1):

Change Your Environment Variables.
System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables

> Variable Name : `NODE_OPTIONS`

> Variable Value : `--max-old-space-size=8192`

Answer (score 0):

> If you hit memory limits with webpack, you can give it more memory with
> `node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/.bin/wp --mode development`
> kind of invocation...  [survivejs-performance](https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/performance/)

if you're not using [webpack nano](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-nano) then use following kind of syntax

`node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/.bin/webpack`